# select item starting from and ending with

Tags: css

we can select the class starting with something like this: `li[class^='item-']` . This selects all lists starting with `item-` but what if I have `item-1 to item-1000` and I would like to select `item-900 to item-1000`.

Is it possible with just css?

Comment: Yes, if you specify all `item-900` to `item-1000` classes. But there is no shorthand for that.

Comment: I guess not possible with css, but you can achieve in JS.

Comment: If you had `item-0001` format instead, then you could just do `li[class^='item-9'], li[class^='item-1'] { .. }`

Comment: @setek um! interesting.